# Java tool for calculating cyclomatic complexity

Tags: java, linux, metrics

I need a tool that allows me to calculate cyclomatic complexity for methods of a given class. Also, I need to do this thing from Linux command line. Until now, I read about Source Monitor, Gmetrics and Sonar, but as far as I know these tools are not providing command line usage.
 Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Checkstyle computes cyclomatic complexity metrics and you can run it [from command line](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/cmdline.html).

Another great tool for static code analysis is PMD, which can also be used [from the console](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/running.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [JArchitect](http://www.jarchitect.com/) tool, a pretty complete static analysis tool available on windows and linux, and it allows you to calculate the [cyclomatic complexity](http://www.jarchitect.com/Metrics#CC) and many other metrics from command line